# "Syntax error on token ID" in Android with Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i have a class like that in the package map1:

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;

public class Map {

    public Bitmap Structure;

    public String name;

    public Integer ID;
}
```

in a different project a have the following code:

```
public class dummy {
    map1.Map MM = new map1.Map();
    MM.ID = 5;//this line is a error: "Syntax error on token "ID", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token"
}
```

i checked the references and all is O.K. (as far as I could tell) 
i have a different and there all works fine. i couldn't find any significant difference, but I'm quite new to eclipse.

why does that happen and how do I make my second project work?

Comment: For "eclipse is trange" read "Eclipse believes my code is invalid, but I can't see why". In general, it's worth assuming that the *compiler* is right, and that the fault lies in your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is broken, basically. This statement:

```
MM.ID = 5;
```

is not inside a constructor, method, or initializer. It needs to be. For example, you might want to put it in a constructor:

```
public class dummy {
    map1.Map MM = new map1.Map();

    public dummy() {
        MM.ID = 5;
    }
}
```

I suspect your other working class *doesn't* have such a syntax error.

(Aside from that, it would be a very good idea to start using private variables, avoiding clashes with standard library types such as `Map`, and following Java naming conventions.)